# JavaScript Object Scope Chain

Tags: javascript, object, scope

I read in the O'Reilly 'High Performace JavaScript' book that the further into the scope chain you go the more performance degrades.

Just to be sure, if I have an object with key:value items and one of these keys has a value that is another object, is this second object further down in the scope chain? They mostly mention functions but also state that functions are objects, so I am just checking.

Please see illustration below if it helps:

```
var object1 = {
key1 : "string1",
key2 : { object2Key1 : "value1",
         object2Key2 : "value2"
       }
```

}

The question is if the items found in key2 are to be considered further down the scope chain of object 1?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It's true that functions are object, but object are not functions. Objects don't have a "scope". Sure, if you are requesting a deeply nested property like `a.b.c.d.e.f.g` it takes a little longer than just requesting one single property. But object lookups normally really fast and I don't think you run into a lot of performance issues with that.

Comment: thanks - is the scope issue mostly or partly to do with having to setup a new execution environment for each function? Also, would scope be the correct term to use when referring to this nested object?

Comment: Yes, I believe it has something to do with establishing a new execution environment, but I'm not absolutely sure about. Object lookups are definitly something different. And no, I think scope wouldn't be the right term. I personally would say "level", for instance in the sentence "this object is 5 level deep", but I'm also not sure if that is technically correct.